# Reading incoming/outgoing bytes from SIM card / ATR

Tags: arduino-uno, softwareserial, uart

I am trying to read data from a two-way I/O uart pin of a sim card on Arduino. It is attached to the GPRS Arduino shield (with SIM900 modem). I believe I have a baud rate issue.

I am supposed to receive ATR (Answer to Reset) bytes which should be easily recongnized but all I get is a almost-random stream of bytes.

I soldered a wire on the SIM I/O pin and attached it to arduino's software serial RX, I set the baud rate to the same baud rate of the modem which goes up to 115,2K and read. Here's my code

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial IO(9, 10); 
void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200); 
IO.begin(115200); // my said wire on SIM card's I/O    enter code here
}
void loop() { 
if (IO.available())
Serial.print(IO.read(),HEX); 
}
```

and here's the output after a cold reset : 
[image]

I also tried other baud rate within the SIM900 range of baud rates, still almost same.

Any idea why it's not showing bytes correctly? I appreciate it if anyone could help.

Comment: what is "GPRS Arduino shield (with SIM900 modem)"?

Comment: why do you print it as HEX and without spaces between? the print(,HEX) doesn't add leading zeros